# i686-linux-android-g++.exe: error: CreateProcess: No such file or directory

Tags: cygwin, android-x86, android-ndk-r7

I am doing ndk-build on windows through cygwin,but I get this error after last .c file gets compiled and this .so file is not generated. I am trying to build a .so file for x86 architecture on Windows 7(my machine is 32 bit).I am using Cygwin compiler to build-ndk.
Using the latest version of android-ndk.

Below is the full error:

Compile x86    : xyz < = test.c
SharedLibrary  : libabc.so
i686-linux-android-g++.exe: error: CreateProcess: No such file or directory
/cygdrive/e/android-ndk/android-ndk-r8e/build/core/build-binary.mk:450: recipe for target `/cygdrive/e/ABC//obj/local/x86/libabc.so' failed